# How to create multiple outputs using a transducer on a pipeline?

Tags: clojure, pipeline

I am trying to understand how to set up a clojure pipeline that has multiple outputs per input, but so far I had no luck getting that to work.

The [documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/pipeline) for pipeline states that

> [...] the transducer will be applied independently to each
>   element [...] and may produce zero or more outputs
>   per input. [...]

However, I fail to understand how to get more than 1 output per input.

I want to apply multiple transformations to the same input and put all results onto the output channel. I am sure this could also be done using [mult](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/mult), [tap](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/tap) and [merge](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/merge), however, this introduces much more overhead compared to adding another transformation to a pipeline transducer.

I tried it with a toy example:

```
  (def ca (chan))
  (def cb (chan))
  (defn f [in] in)
  (defn g [in] (* 2 in))
  (pipeline 1 cb  (map (juxt f g)) ca)
  (put! ca 1)
  (<!! cb)
```

However, this outputs [1 2] in a single output instead of two separate outputs.

So: How can I set up a clojure pipeline between two channels such that it produces multiple (>1) outputs on the output channel per input on the input channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mapcat` instead of `map`.  The difference is: map is one to one, while mapcat is one to many.